# Как загрузить Верстку на OpenCart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, opencart

нужна помощь, как загрузить готовую Вёрстку сайта на OpenCart. Сайт свёрстан на  HTML, CSS, JS и фотки нужно с админ понели загрузить, но не знаю как.

Прощу помочь, если у кого нибудь был опыт с OpenCart.

Comment: "Загрузить" -- это так не работает. Для этого нужно создать тему, где Вы сможете использовать Ваш HTML в twig (в случае с OpenCart 3) либо tpl (в случае с версией ниже 3) шаблонах, куда сможете выводить информацию из админ панели, сможете подключить свой CSS и JS и так далее.

Comment: можете детально рассказать прошу ваc?  у меня есть готовый сайт на HTML, CSS, JS и фотки, нужно их добавить на OpenCard (Версия ocStore 3.0.3.7)

Comment: Это очень много текста и для этого есть документация, статьи, видео уроки и другие источники информации. [How to create OpenCart theme](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=How+to+create+OpenCart+theme)

Comment: извените еще раз, я не смог создать тему у меня нет доступа к корневым файлам сайта а есть только доступ к админ панели. я не совсем понел как конвертировать html в twig. прошу помочь если что могу дать доступ к админке)

Comment: Едва ли здесь как-то поможет доступ к админке. Обратитесь на фриланс, потому что Вы не в полной мере понимаете что Вам нужно делать и с чем Вы столкнулись и это нельзя описать парочкой предложений.